# how do i drag and launch in untiy 2d?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am a newbie in c# and i have been trying to get some code that will help me launch my character in the opposite direction of the drag. Like Angry Birds but i don't want the character to move while i am dragging. Here is my script that i copied from a video and it isn't working.

```
`using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class OrbMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float launchSpeed = 100;
    Vector3 _initialPosition;
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    private Vector2 directionToInitialPosition;

    private void Awake()
    {
        _initialPosition = transform.position;
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        directionToInitialPosition = _initialPosition - transform.position;
    }

    private void OnMouseUp()
    {
        rb.AddForce(directionToInitialPosition *launchSpeed);
    }

    private void OnMouseDrag()
    {
        Vector3 newPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        transform.position = new Vector3(newPosition.x, newPosition.y);
    }

}
`
```

help me with a script that will launch my character opposite of the drag. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just remove the

```
    private void OnMouseDrag()
    {
        Vector3 newPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        transform.position = new Vector3(newPosition.x, newPosition.y);
    }
```

this part of the script means that everytime the player drag the mouse/touch then the gameobject will follow the mouse. Because you don't want it, you can just remove it to

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class OrbMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float launchSpeed = 100;
    Vector3 _initialPosition;
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    private Vector2 directionToInitialPosition;

    private void Awake()
    {
        _initialPosition = transform.position;
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        directionToInitialPosition = _initialPosition - transform.position;
    }

    private void OnMouseUp()
    {
        rb.AddForce(directionToInitialPosition *launchSpeed);
    }
}
```

Comment: i have removed it but my character isn't moving on mouse up. Can you suggest any other script or some improvements please.

Comment: @Koushal so you want your character to only follow your mouse up and down (y axis) but not left and right? (x axis)